# Unable to delete Azure Data Factory - DeleteFactoryBlockedByIR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to delete a Azure Data Factory

```
There was an error while deleting the data factory. Please stop all SSIS Integration Runtimes, remove all Azure VNet Integration Runtimes and remove all Self-Hosted Integration Runtimes sharing before deleting your Data Factory.
0 Azure VNet Integration Runtimes: .
0 Shared Self-hosted Integration Runtimes: .
1 Azure SSIS Integration Runtimes with status: Started: integrationRuntime1 ; . DeleteFactoryBlockedByIR
```

When in the UI, the delete options are greyed out.

[image]

How can I delete the factory?

Comment: Refresh the page then stop the Azure SSIS Integration Runtimes, if the status is not stopped, it's not able to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Noticed the log infomation in your error message：`1 Azure SSIS Integration Runtimes with status: Started:`.

Based on the steps which are listed in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/manage-azure-ssis-integration-runtime#delete-an-azure-ssis-ir) and the details in the error message:

[image]

you need to stop the IRs first so that you can reconfigure or remove them.